# Ubuntu 16.10 - Desktop crashes after login

Tags: 16.10, .desktop

I didn't found anything related to my problem, so I hope you guys can help me. Soon after logging into my account, background turns black and desktop crashes. Then it returns to login screen. Strangely, it seems to work if I log in with guest account or if I use Unity. I tried to run the safe mode, but same problem appears. Any clue of what it can be?

Comment: try this #sudo chown USER:USER /home #sudo chown USER:USER /home/USER #sudo chmod -R 755 /home #sudo chmod -R 755 /home/USER

Comment: Mass chown/chmod changes is not a good idea. There are files/permissions that are different than what you suggest.

Comment: What desktop/display manager are you using if it's not Ubuntu/LightDM?